# Custom UniqueUsername validation with Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I want to assure that the username is unique when creating a new one or updating one username. I wrote the code below and it works fine for creating and updating the username. But when updating only other user fields, like age or sex, and maintaining the same username, it returns invalid because the username already exists.

It's important to say that the validation I want is using BindingResult. I already have a database which considers username a unique constraint. But now I want the same validation with BindingResult. But the way I did causes error when updating an user.

Defining of the annotation @UniqueUsername

```
package app.condominio.validator;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueUsernameValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UniqueUsername {
    String message() default "Nome de usuário já está sendo usado";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Implementing the validator

```
package app.condominio.validator;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import app.condominio.service.UsuarioService;

public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueUsername username) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        return !usuarioService.existe(username);
    }
}
```

In Usuario.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Usuarios")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
@UniqueUsername
private String username;

@NotBlank
private String password;

@NotBlank
private String nome;

@Email
private String email;

...
```

UsuarioService

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UsuarioServiceImpl implements UsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioDao usuarioDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public boolean existe(String username) {
        return usuarioDao.existsByUsername(username);
    }
```

UsuarioDao

```
public interface UsuarioDao extends CrudRepository<Usuario, Long> {

    Usuario findByUsername(String username);
    
    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);

}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("conta")
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @GetMapping("/cadastrar/sindico")
    public ModelAndView preCadastro(@ModelAttribute("usuario") Usuario usuario, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("conteudo", "cadastrarSindico");
        return new ModelAndView("site/layout", model);
    }

    @PostMapping("/cadastrar/sindico")
    public ModelAndView posCadastro(@Valid @ModelAttribute("usuario") Usuario usuario, BindingResult validacao, ModelMap model) {
        if (validacao.hasErrors()) {
            return preCadastro(usuario, model);
        }
        usuarioService.salvarSindico(usuario);
        model.addAttribute(usuario);
        model.addAttribute("conteudo", "cadastrarCondominio");
        return new ModelAndView("site/layout", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following approach using validation groups:

Create a marker interface (or class)

```
public interface UserCreateValidationGroup {
}
```

Then use it in you entity like following

```
@NotBlank
@UniqueUsername(groups = UserCreateValidationGroup.class)
private String username;
```

And then use it in Controller along with `@Validated` (Spring's variant for JSR-303). Note that you'll have to split your single method into separate create and update methods, to distinct validation.

Create:

```
@PostMapping("/cadastrar/sindico")
public ModelAndView create(
    @Validated(UserCreateValidationGroup.class) @ModelAttribute("usuario") Usuario usuario, 
    BindingResult validacao, 
    ModelMap model
) { ... }
```

Update:

```
// note, here I did use PUT and no argument for @Validated annotation
@PutMapping("/cadastrar/sindico") 
public ModelAndView update(
    @Validated @ModelAttribute("usuario") Usuario usuario, 
    BindingResult validacao, 
    ModelMap model
) { ... }
```

However, you'll have to perform manual check (`UsuarioService.existe`) for username in the update case.

Comment: almost there... Is there a way to combine @ Valid and @ Validation? I have in my entity other annotations such as @ NotBlank. When I use @ Validated(UserCreateValidationGroup.class) in my controller, all default validations are skipped. I dont wanna put (groups = UserCreateValidationGroup.class) in @ NotBlank too.

Answer (score 2):

I think `UniqueUsernameValidator` actions as expected.

I am not very clear about your application.So it is difficult to implement an method to to check if validating user have the same id or not of user in database.May be you should provide more details, such as code of method `usuarioService.existe(username)`.

For me, to assure that the username is unique, i do this:

```
@Column(unique=true)
String username;
```

or use @UniqueConstraint

```
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "username"
    })
})
```

but **note** that it will work if you let JPA create your tables.

- [@UniqueConstraint](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html)

Comment: What I want is a bending validation. I'll updated my question with more code for best undertanding, thanks